Вытащить id записи при добавлении либо игнорирования на случай наличия
INSERT IGNORE INTO `stats` (`title`) VALUES (?)

Поле title содержит уникальные имена. При попытке добавление записи с именем которое уже есть в таблице, проигнорирует и не запишет...
Чтобы получить id записи которой добавил $this->db_id->lastInsertId().
Но что если запись не была добавлена по причине того, что имя уже есть в таблице. Возможно ли сразу получить id записи из таблицы, которая была проигнорирована?
Не удобно, допустим сперва добавляем недостающие записи, затем делаем запрос, чтобы получить массив id записей которые уже были и которые добавили...
Если при добавлении записи возможно получить id, наверное и в моем случаи при игнорировании возможно также получить id строчки из-за которой проигнорировали, не стали добавлять запись...

Вопрос только один: зачем знать идентификатор этой строчки? Какой в этом смысл? Какая задача решается таким образом?

MySQL не поддерживает RETURNING. Ответ - нет.

возможно вам поможетINSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Statement https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.4/en/insert-on-duplicate.html
